# How can I make require() use node_modules in Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: parse-platform, cloud, parse-cloud-code

I can happily upload `npm` module source, but if I try to `require('foo')` then it ignores the `node_modules` directory, unless I exactly specify `require('./node_modules/foo/index.js')`.

How can I work around this to use npm modules on parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Parse supports npm, I'm using http://browserify.org/ to bundle all my code into a single `cloud.js` file and then uploading that.

Answer (score 1):

Parse does not support npm now. You have to locate it manually. 
There are still problem about it. Suppose I added 'cheerio' like this require('cloud/cheerio'), so parse will get the cheerio module. But cheerio has some dependencies. So inside the cheerio source code you will see there are lots of require('.........'), if you want to use cheerio you have edit them require('cloud/cheerio/lib/path/etc.........'), which is a very bad solution. Even parse cloud do not lets you upload json file. Cheerio use few json files for him.

So for now you can't add npm with parse. It's a MAJOR fault of parse in this world of javascript.